# Organising Album products in CartThrob

Tags: cartthrob

What's the best way to do organise music album products in CartThrob? Each album would be available to buy as a CD and/or download. And then each track from the album would be available to buy individually. So I was thinking that each item (CD and downloads) would need to be separate products. I could then group them on an album page by treating the album as a department with a separate channel and pulling all the product items onto the album page using a related field in the channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

('m with Vector, the people behind CartThrob)

This is a perfect use case for packages: https://www.cartthrob.com/docs/fieldtypes/packages/index.html

Each track can be set up as a product in one channel, and you can organize them into albums via packages in another channel. Then you can sell them individually or together.

Comment: OK. This answers my query about setting up each track as one product.